# What are the pair of IPs or "unknown" in the Apache server logs?

Tags: apache-2.2, log-files

The last "column" in my Apache server logs lists either a pair of IPs, one single IP, or is empty (i.e. "-"). Sometimes the first in a pair of IPs is "unknown". It looks something like this:

```
"unknown, 141.91.240.141"
"172.26.243.42"
"-"
"10.14.2.6, 10.14.2.65"
```

What is that?

*I'm on a shared server and cannot access the config file.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Such IPs are usually the content of the X-Forwarded-For header. That header is added by http proxies like `squid` in order to tell the server what client the request is made for. If the request goes through several proxies they will add the IPs in a list.